# process shared binary semaphore

Tags: c, mutex, semaphore, race-condition

I've created a binary semaphore that can be shared between two processes using `pthread_mutex_t`, `pthread_cond_t` and `bool` flag. But I've a little doubt of my implementation regarding the initialization of the `mutex` and `condvar` attributes(race condition if Pro1 is created first and then Pro2 or Pro2 created first and then Pro1). This is my code:

Pro1.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct bs_attr {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cvar;
    bool flag;
};

struct bs_attr *bs_attr_obj;

void post() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
    bs_attr_obj->flag = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&bs_attr_obj->cvar);
}

void wait() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
    while (!bs_attr_obj->flag)
        pthread_cond_wait(&bs_attr_obj->cvar, &bs_attr_obj->mutex);
    bs_attr_obj->flag = false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
}

void create_shm(const char *bin_sem_ID, const bool create, const int flags, const int mode) {
    int bs_attr_obj_ID;
    if ((bs_attr_obj_ID = shm_open(bin_sem_ID, flags, mode)) == -1) {
        printf("shm_open failed with %s\n", bin_sem_ID);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (create) {
        if (ftruncate(bs_attr_obj_ID, sizeof(bs_attr)) == -1) {
            printf("ftruncate failed with %s\n", bin_sem_ID);

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if ((bs_attr_obj = (bs_attr *)(mmap(NULL, sizeof(bs_attr), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, bs_attr_obj_ID, 0))) == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("mmap failed with %s\n", bin_sem_ID);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (create) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
        bs_attr_obj->flag = false;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
    }
}

int main() {
    const char *bin_sem_ID = "/BIN_SEM1";
    create_shm(bin_sem_ID, true, O_CREAT | O_RDWR | O_TRUNC, S_IRWXU | S_IRWXG);
    
    // IS THE BELOW PART A RACE CONDITION?
    /* set mutex shared between processes */
    pthread_mutexattr_t mutex_attr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutex_attr);
    if (pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutex_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED) != 0) {
        printf("mutex attribute process shared error %s\n", bin_sem_ID);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pthread_mutex_init(&bs_attr_obj->mutex, &mutex_attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutex_attr);

    /* set cvar shared between processes */
    pthread_condattr_t cvar_attr;
    pthread_condattr_init(&cvar_attr);
    if (pthread_condattr_setpshared(&cvar_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED) != 0) {
        printf("condition variable attribute process shared error %s\n", bin_sem_ID);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pthread_cond_init(&bs_attr_obj->cvar, &cvar_attr);
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&cvar_attr);

    while (true) {
        post();
        printf("signal posted\n");

        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Pro2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

struct bs_attr {
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    pthread_cond_t cvar;
    bool flag;
};

struct bs_attr *bs_attr_obj;

void post() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
    bs_attr_obj->flag = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
    pthread_cond_signal(&bs_attr_obj->cvar);
}

void wait() {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
    while (!bs_attr_obj->flag)
        pthread_cond_wait(&bs_attr_obj->cvar, &bs_attr_obj->mutex);
    bs_attr_obj->flag = false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
}

void create_shm(const char *bin_sem_ID, const bool create, const int flags, const int mode) {
    int bs_attr_obj_ID;
    if ((bs_attr_obj_ID = shm_open(bin_sem_ID, flags, mode)) == -1) {
        printf("shm_open failed with %s\n", bin_sem_ID);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (create) {
        if (ftruncate(bs_attr_obj_ID, sizeof(bs_attr)) == -1) {
            printf("ftruncate failed with %s\n", bin_sem_ID);

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    if ((bs_attr_obj = (bs_attr *)(mmap(NULL, sizeof(bs_attr), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, bs_attr_obj_ID, 0))) == MAP_FAILED) {
        printf("mmap failed with %s\n", bin_sem_ID);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (create) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
        bs_attr_obj->flag = false;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&bs_attr_obj->mutex);
    }
}

int main() {
    const char *bin_sem_ID = "/BIN_SEM1";
    create_shm(bin_sem_ID, false, O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWUSR | S_IWGRP);
    
    // IS THE BELOW PART A RACE CONDITION?
    /* set mutex shared between processes */
    pthread_mutexattr_t mutex_attr;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutex_attr);
    if (pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutex_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED) != 0) {
        printf("mutex attribute process shared error %s\n", bin_sem_ID);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pthread_mutex_init(&bs_attr_obj->mutex, &mutex_attr);
    pthread_mutexattr_destroy(&mutex_attr);

    /* set cvar shared between processes */
    pthread_condattr_t cvar_attr;
    pthread_condattr_init(&cvar_attr);
    if (pthread_condattr_setpshared(&cvar_attr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED) != 0) {
        printf("condition variable attribute process shared error %s\n", bin_sem_ID);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    pthread_cond_init(&bs_attr_obj->cvar, &cvar_attr);
    pthread_condattr_destroy(&cvar_attr);

    while (true) {
        wait();
        printf("signal received\n");

        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all I recommend you learn how to create projects using multiple source file to create a single program. Then you can put common code in a separate source files used by both programs.

Comment: As for your problem, do the initialization of the mutex and conditional variable in *one* of the two programs (probably the one creating the shared memory segment), and use some other IPC way to synchronize the two programs, so the second can wait on that to open the shared memory segment and start working.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the suggestion. Will do code re-usability factoring after the doubts I've about my implementation are clarified.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Actually I thought of initializing `mutex` and `condvar` only in `Pro1`, but the issue I faced is when `Pro2`(don't initialize `mutex` and `condvar`) runs for the first time(ofcourse after `Pro1` has started) everything works as expected but if I kill `Pro2` using Ctrl^C and then rerun `Pro2`, `Pro1` stops sending signal